# postcode and kilometer on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new to working with google maps. I want to display a map when the user enters a post code and then selects "km". The map should display shops in the selected area, within a kilometer. How can I do this?

[See this example](http://www.hm.com/no/store-locator).

If you select option 2 from the radio buttons, I want the same behavior. First post code and then select kilometer then search in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html).  First, you could use the [autocomplete widget](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html) with the geocode option on.

And then you could use the places [search widget](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search.html) with the location parameter being the result of the autocomplete, and the radius being the number of meters you're interested in having results for.